# Search box disappears when clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a sliding image panel that uses

```
$('input').click(function() {
$(this).parent().slideUp();
```

Unfortunately the input part on the sliding panel causes the search box at the top of the page to disappear when clicked on because the search form uses "input type="text" etc. is there a way to get around this? Here is the code that makes the sliding panel work http://jsfiddle.net/pcD8D/7/

and the code for the searchform is:

```
            <!--BEGIN #searchform-->
            <form class="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>">
                <input type="text" class="textBox" name="s" onclick="this.value=''"   value="Enter your search" tabindex="1" />
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/clearBtn.png" width="17" height="17" class="cancelBtn" alt="ClearBtn" />
            <!--END #searchform-->
            </form
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make your selector more specific to target just the input you want:

```
$("#team_section .team_member_photo").next().hide().append('<input type="button" value="close" name="close" />');

$("input[name=close]").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```